# Method loading in Spring Boot even though it's not specified in Spring Boot Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled, spring-profiles

I have a method that I don't want loaded in my Local Spring profile. The method is

```
@Profile("prod")
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 21600000)
public void updateHackalistHackathonData() {
...
}
```

I have created an `application.properties'`, `application-local.properties'` and `application-prod.properties` file in the same location `src/java/resources`. In `application.properties`, I mentioned `spring.profiles.active=local`.

However, this method which is a scheduled one still goes into execution. How do I stop this?

Comment: Could you put your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configuration (xml or annotation) and web.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `@Profile("prod")` annotation on class (bean) definition not method itself. E.g.:

```
@Component
@Profile("prod")
public class HackatonScheduler{
    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 21600000)
    public void updateHackalistHackathonData() {
        ...
    }
}
```